# Searching using multiple keywords in PHP/MySql

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm trying to search for people based on their skills by using different keywords. However, whenever I try to search, the results are narrowed down to match the exact keywords.

Example:

table for users:

```
ID           Name                  Skills
 1       Joe Smith         Cooking Dancing Painting 
 2       John Williams     Drawing Fishing
 3       Beth Gray         Cooking Swimming 
 4       Martin Torres     Dancing Repairing CPR
 5       Alice Lee         Cooking Drawing Welding
```

If you search using the word "Cooking", it will return 3 results which are 1,3 and 5 which is okay. However if you search using "Cooking Drawing", it will only return 1 result which is 5 who has both Cooking and Drawing. What I am trying to achieve is for it to return ALL the people who have at least 1 of the skills in the `keywords`, in this case, 1,2,3 and 5.

Thanks.

Comment: please put your query or code here ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM volunteerbio WHERE (volunteerSpecialSkills LIKE '%Cooking%' AND volunteerSpecialSkills LIKE '%Dancing%')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Mysql `Fulltext` search feature.

Here is query you can use in your code with full-text:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name
WHERE MATCH (yourcolumn1,yourcolumn2,...)
AGAINST ('your texts to search');
```

Note : You should apply `fulltext` `index` on columns in which you want to search.

You can make query with `like` with combination of `AND` `OR` Conditions :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (skills LIKE '%Cooking%' AND skills LIKE '%Dancing%' ... )
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (skills LIKE '%Cooking%' OR skills LIKE '%Dancing%' ... )
```

Comment: Worked great. I just had to convert my tables since I was using InnoDB.